# How to prove that $\frac{\log(1+a/x)}{\log(1+1/x)}$ is increasing, for $a\geq 1$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need to prove that the sequence 
$$
\frac{\log\big(1+\frac{a}{k}\big)}{\log\big(1+\frac{1}{k}\big)}
$$
is increasing for any $a\geq 1$, so that I thought of defining
$$ 
f(x)=\frac{\log\big(1+\frac{a}{x}\big)}{\log\big(1+\frac{1}{x}\big)}
$$
and prove that $f'(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\geq 1$. In view of some graphs I plotted, this function seems to be increasing. Moreover, it is easily seen from the expression that its limit will be precisely $a$. However, when trying to prove that $f'\geq 0$, I arrive to
$$
\frac{\log\big(1+\frac{a}{x}\big)}{1+\frac{1}{x}}-\frac{a\log\big(1+\frac{1}{x}\big)}{1+\frac{a}{x}} \overbrace{\geq}^?0.
$$
At that point I do not know how to proceed, so any hint would be kindly appreciated.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For later use, consider the function $\phi(x) = x \log x$, for which $\phi'(x) = 1 + \log x$ and $\phi''(x) = \frac{1}{x}$; in particular, $\phi$ is convex on $[1, \infty)$.

If
$$
f(x) = \frac{\log\bigl(1 + \frac{a}{x}\bigr)}{\log\bigl(1 + \frac{1}{x}\bigr)},
$$
then
$$
f'(x) = \frac{(x + a) \log\bigl(1 + \frac{a}{x}\bigr) - a(x + 1) \log\bigl(1 + \frac{1}{x}\bigr)}{(x + a)(x + 1)x \log^{2}\bigl(1 + \frac{1}{x}\bigr)}.
$$
The denominator is positive for $x \geq 1$, and the numerator is equal to
\begin{align*}
(x + a) &\log\bigl(1 + \tfrac{a}{x}\bigr) - a(x + 1) \log\bigl(1 + \tfrac{1}{x}\bigr) \\
  &= (x + a) \bigl[\log(x + a) - \log x\bigr] - a(x + 1) \bigl[\log(x + 1) - \log x\bigr] \\
  &= (x + a) \log(x + a) - a(x + 1) \log(x + 1) - \bigl[(x + a) - a(x + 1)\bigr]\log x \\
  &= (x + a) \log(x + a) - a(x + 1) \log(x + 1) + (a - 1) x \log x \\
  &= \phi(x + a) - a \phi(x + 1) + (a - 1) \phi(x).
\tag{1}
\end{align*}
Since $x + 1 = \frac{a - 1}{a} x + \frac{1}{a} (x + a)$, convexity of $\phi$ implies
$$
\phi(x + 1) \leq \tfrac{a - 1}{a} \phi(x) + \tfrac{1}{a} \phi(x + a),
$$
or
$$
a \phi(x + 1) \leq \phi(x + a) + (a - 1) \phi(x).
$$
That is, (1) is non-negative, so $f$ is non-decreasing (and strictly increasing if $a > 1$, since $\phi$ is strictly convex).

Comment: Great answer! Thank you very much! By the way, this proves that $\frac{x}{x+a}\geq \big(\frac{x}{x+1}\big)^a$ for all $x\geq 1$, and $a\geq 1$.

Comment: @Alberto: You're welcome; it was a fun problem! :) (On a tangent, the inequality in your comment gave me a brief scare: By Newton's binomial theorem, $(x + 1)^{a} \geq x^{a} + ax^{a-1} = x^{a-1}(x + a)$, and this easily rearranges to $\frac{x}{x+a} \geq \left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^{a}$. But this inequality doesn't appear to be _equivalent_ to the one in your post...?)

Comment: In fact it is one-way. I wanted to find $b>0$ such that $\frac{x}{x+a}\geq \big(\frac{x}{x+1}\big)^b$ for every $x\geq 1$. Arranging this a bit you get the condition that $b\geq \frac{\log(1+a/x)}{\log(1+1/x)}$. Proving that this function increases, actually allows you to take $b$ equal to the limit of the function, which is precisely $a$ (and it is the best possible). This was to prove the equivalence of two definitions for quasi-monotone sequences. BTW, the thing you said about Newton's binomial thm. just made me realize I was stupidly complicating the job :(, so for sure I won't forget it.

Comment: @Alberto: As the saying goes, "A mathematician's reputation rests on the number of bad proofs (s)he has given", meaning "pioneering work is clumsy". That is, we've all been in the situation of over-complicating things. :)